$\min\{X,Y\}$; where $X,Y$ are geometric random variables

Does $\min\{X,Y\}$ follow a geometric distribution? $X \sim BN(1,p); Y \sim BN(1,q)$ independent

$$P(\min\{X,Y \}=k)=P( \min\{X,Y\} \geq k)-P(\min\{X,Y \} \geq k+1)=\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}(1-p)^{n-1}p\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}(1-q)^{n-1}q-\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}(1-p)^{n-1}p\sum_{n=k+1}^{\infty}(1-q)^{n-1}q=(1-p)^{k-1}(1-q)^{k-1}-(1-p)^{k}(1-q)^{k}=[(1-p)(1-q)]^{k-1}(1-(1-p)(1-q))$$
And it'd follow that:
$$\min\{X,Y \} \sim BN(1,1-(1-p)(1-q))$$

I would have thought a negative binomial distribution with parameters $1$ and $p$ would be called a geometric distribution with parameter $p$.

But yes, this is correct for the minimum of independent geometric distributed random variables , perhaps most easily shown by considering the probability that none of the random variables is $\le k$ (the survival function as the product of the complements of the individual CDFs).

The geometric distribution supported on the set $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ with $\Pr(X=1) = p$ is most simply characterized by saying $\Pr(X>n) = (1-p)^n.$
In other words, if the probability of success on each trial is $p,$ then the probability of getting $n$ failures on the first $n$ trials, which is the same as $\Pr(X>n),$ is $(1-p)^n.$
\begin{align}
& \Pr(\min\{X,Y\}>x) = \Pr(X>x\ \&\ Y>x) \\[6pt]
= {} & \Pr(X>x)\Pr(Y>x) = (1-p)^n(1-q)^n \\[6pt]
= {} & (1-r)^n \\
& \text{where } r = 1-(1-p)(1-q) = p+q-pq.
\end{align}
Therefore $\min\{X,Y\}$ has a geometric distribution.
You can also think of it like this: You throw two biased dice, one having probability $p$ of giving you a $1$ and the other having probability $q$ of giving you a $1.$ For either die, the number of trials needed to get a $1$ has a geometric distribution. You throw both of them. If you don't get at least one $1,$ throw them both again. And if you still don't get at least one $1,$ throw them both again. And so on.
The probability of getting at least one $1$ when you throw them both is $p+q-pq.$ If "success" means getting at least one $1,$ then there you have it.

Wikipedia says

The minimum of $n$ geometric random variables with parameters $p_1, \ldots, p_n$ is also geometrically distributed with parameter
$$1 - \prod_{i=1}^n (1 - p_i)$$

citing Ciardo, Leemis and Nicol 1995.
